# How can I repeat audio without stopping it?

Tags: android, audio

I want to repeat playing audio. so if first clicking button audio play, and second clicking same button repeat same audio without stopping. How can I do this? Here's what I've tried:

```
if (mp != null){
                mp.stop();
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.seekTo(0);
                mp = null;
            }
            else {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Takbiratul_Ihram.this, R.raw.takbir_cowok);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
                    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer arg0){
                        mp = null;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

More information here [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)